# create internal db file android sqlite

Tags: android, database, file, android-studio, storage

I'm trying to create internal db file when data submit to database.when user enter values to textfields and click on the button,'SAMPLE.db' db file should create inside 'MYTEST' file on internal storage.this is my code.but it's not working.

-Main Activity oncreate-

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String Id=mEDitTxt.getText().toString();
                    String Unm=mEDitTxt2.getText().toString();


                    insertconfig(Id, Unm);
                    DbBackup.copyDatabase(getApplicationContext());

                }
            });
```

-DBbackup-

```
public class DbBackup {

    public static void copyDatabase(Context c) {

        String DATABASE_NAME = "SAMPLE.db";

        String databasePath = c.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
        File f = new File(databasePath);
        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        OutputStream myOutputInternal = null;
        InputStream myInput = null;
        Log.d("testing", " lots db path " + databasePath);
        Log.d("testing", " lots db exist " + f.exists());

        if (f.exists()) {
            try {


                File directoryIntenal = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MYTEST/");



                if (!directoryIntenal.exists())
                    directoryIntenal.mkdir();

                myOutputInternal = new FileOutputStream(directoryIntenal.getAbsolutePath()
                        + "/" + DATABASE_NAME);

                myInput = new FileInputStream(databasePath);


                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                    myOutputInternal.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }


                myOutputInternal.flush();

            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                try {

                    if (myOutputInternal != null) {
                        myOutputInternal.close();
                        myOutputInternal = null;
                    }
                    if (myInput != null) {
                        myInput.close();
                        myInput = null;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show Logcat errors. If nothing displays change catch statement: `catch (Exception e) { Log.e(TAG, "Error", e) }`

Answer (score 0):

Call this method when you want to **export OR import** your database ,

```
public class DbExportImport {

    public static final String TAG = DbExportImport.class.getName();

    /**
     * Directory that files are to be read from and written to *
     */

    public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.vcs.androiddatabaseexample";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "crud.db";


    public static final File DATA_DIRECTORY_DATABASE = new File(
            Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/" + PACKAGE_NAME
                    + "/databases/" + DATABASE_NAME);

    public static final String DATA_DIRECTORY_DATABASE_PATH =
            Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/" + PACKAGE_NAME
                    + "/databases/" + DATABASE_NAME;

    public static boolean exportSyncDbNew(String Filename, String FolderPath) {
        if (!SdIsPresent())
            return false;

        File dbFile = DATA_DIRECTORY_DATABASE;
        if (dbFile.exists()) {
            // String filename = Filename+"_SAT.db";
            File exportDir = new File(FolderPath);
            if (!exportDir.exists()) {
                exportDir.mkdirs();
            }
            File file = new File(exportDir, Filename);
            Utils.printLoge(5, "#### exportDir", "-->" + FolderPath);
            Utils.printLoge(5, "#### Filename", "-->" + Filename);
            Utils.printLoge(5, "DATA_DIRECTORY_DATABASE", "-->" + DATA_DIRECTORY_DATABASE);
            try {
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    copyFile(dbFile, file);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                Constant.isFielCopeError = true;
                Constant.fileCopeException = "Upload: " + Utils.ConvertExceptionToString(e);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            Constant.isFielCopeError = true;
            Constant.fileCopeException = "Upload: DB not available";
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean restoreDownloadedDb(String FileName) {
        if (!SdIsPresent())
            return false;

        File exportFile = DATA_DIRECTORY_DATABASE;
        //File importFile = IMPORT_Downloaded_FILE;
        File importFile = new File(Constant.ECTERNAL_STORAGE_APP_USER1, FileName);


        if (exportFile.exists()) {
            exportFile.delete();
//            Log.e(TAG, "exportFile delete");
        }

        if (!importFile.exists()) {
//            Log.d(TAG, "File does not exist");
            return false;
        }

        try {
            exportFile.createNewFile();
            //copyFile(importFile, exportFile);
            copyDataBase(importFile, exportFile);
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Utils.printLoge(5, "restoreDownloadedDb", "error-->" + e.getMessage().toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```